# React variable value never getting used in find function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Take a look at the code below. I'm passing `userId` into my action but it's value is never being used. Maybe I'm using the `find` function in a wrong way, some help is appreciated.

```
export const getUserInfo = (userId) => dispatch =>{
    axios.get("http://localhost:5000/users")
    .then((res) =>{
        const userInfo = res.find((userId) =>{
            return res.data.id === userId;
        })
        dispatch({
            type: USER_INFO,
            payload:  userInfo
        })
    })
}
```

Edit: What I want to do is to match the `res.data.id` with a given `userId`.

Comment: just `console.log()` your `res` and see where your data is saved.
it should be something like `res.data` and there you can use like `res.data.find...`

Comment: I don't understand, my data being saved?

Comment: `res` brings the data, the status sent from server and more other properties
while `res` is an object, you have to access the object's property where you can find your `id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the `userId` in find function param and replace with `data` instead of `userId`

```
export const getUserInfo = (userId) => dispatch =>{
    axios.get("http://localhost:5000/users")
    .then((res) =>{
        const userInfo = res.find((data) =>{ //<= change the param
            return data.id === userId; // remove the res and call from data
        })
        dispatch({
            type: USER_INFO,
            payload:  userInfo
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The userId in find function is a scope variable, so it´s different from the one you  are passing as parameter of your function. The right way to find elementId would be:

```js
 const userInfo = res.find((element) =>{
            return element.data.id === userId;
        })
```